# Xamarin forms - unwanted extra space under TableView

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, tableview

I am creating my first Android app. I want to show TableView with some input fields and then a button to process the inputs.
I don't know why but there is extra space under TableView or the button is aligned to the bottom but it is opposite to the settings.

Can you help me fix it?

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Start"  Padding="20,15,20,0" Spacing="0">
    <Label Text="This is TableView"></Label>
    <TableView Intent="Settings" VerticalOptions="Start">
        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="item 1"/>
                        <Entry></Entry>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="item 2"/>
                        <Entry></Entry>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </TableSection>
        </TableRoot>
    </TableView>
    <Label Text="TableView - END"></Label>
    <Button Text="My button" TextColor="DodgerBlue" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Margin="40, 10, 40, 10"/>

    <Frame VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Black">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                <Label Text="aaaa" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"></Label>
                <Label Text="value" HorizontalOptions="End"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="aaaa"></Label>
                <Label Text="value"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="aaaa"></Label>
                <Label Text="value"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to define the RowHeight for each cell, and then specify the HeightRequest for the tableview. this way you can define the space it will occupy

```
<TableView Margin="0" Intent="Settings"  HeightRequest="120" RowHeight="60" VerticalOptions="Start">
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is how Xamarin.Forms TableView/ListView works. It is not expected to have anything below it. If you need something below you can either set the height of TableView manually or to put the content in the last cell, neither thing is perfect but in any case you need to look for some workaround as this is behavior by design (it would be a bit easier if you could use the ListView instead of TableView).

Comment: Can you suggest what else should I use instead of TableView? I was thinking about Grid but there is no line row separator and I would like to have it.

Answer (score 1):

As you were asking what you can do besides using a `TableView`, of course a `Grid` would be possible, please see the following example:

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" /> <!-- for the label -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1" /> <!-- For the separator, you might have to experiment with the height -->
        <RowDefinition Height="*" /> 
        <RowDefinition Height="1" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Text="Item 1" />
    <Entry Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Black" 
             HeightRequest="1" 
             Grid.Row="1" 
             Grid.Column="0" 
             Grid.ColumnSpan="2" /> <!-- The separator -->
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Item 2" />
    <Entry Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Black" 
             HeightRequest="1" 
             Grid.Row="3" 
             Grid.Column="0" 
             Grid.ColumnSpan="2" /> <!-- The separator -->
</Grid>
```

I am using `BoxView`s with a black background color and a `HeightRequest` of `1` for the separator. You might have to experiment with the color and the height to get the results you want. Values below `1` are possible and result in finer lines. In a real world example I've used `.5`.

Anyway, this makes the XAML way more cluttered. `Grid`-designs (while I am using them myself) tend to get quite unwieldy.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this what you are looking for but my understanding of the question tells me you are talking about the label `Value` being away from the rest.

if you check the code for this label :

```
  <Label Text="value" HorizontalOptions="End"></Label>
```

the `HorizontalOptions` is set to `"End"` which is causing this changing it to start will fix your problem

Feel free to revert in case if I missed anything

Goodluck

Comment: No, this is not the case. The problem is about blank space between table view and the button. Sorry for confusion.